# How do I render a controller action without a layout?

Tags: layout, controller, action, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a particular controller action that I want to render without any layout.

I tried to render without a plug at the controller level, but it didn't work.

```
defmodule Hello.PageController do
  use Hello.Web, :controller

  plug :put_layout, nil

  def landing(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "landing.html"
  end
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason `plug :put_layout, nil` does not work is because [the `put_layout` plug only considers `false` to mean "don't use any layout"](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/f2e02d97ef79f825f6bbbdc2d7b69a1d005bff90/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L400-L415). `nil` is treated just like any other atom and Phoenix tries to render `nil.html`:

> Could not render "nil.html" for MyApp.LayoutView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "web/templates/layout". The following templates were compiled:
>
> - app.html

The fix is to use `false`:

```
plug :put_layout, false
```

If you want to restrict the plug to certain actions, you can pass `when`:

```
plug :put_layout, false when action in [:index, :show]
```

Answer (score 11):

You just need to invoke `put_layout` and pass it the conn and false.

```
def landing(conn, _params) do
  conn = put_layout conn, false
  render conn, "landing.html"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are running a LiveVeiw app, you'll likely have a `plug :put_root_layout, {MyAppWeb.LayoutView, :root}` in your browser pipeline.

In which case `put_layout(false)` will only disable the app layout, so you'll have to use `conn |> put_root_layout(false)` to disable root layout.

You are probably looking to disable both, so you'll need:

```
conn
|> put_layout(false) # disable app.html.eex layout
|> put_root_layout(false) # disable root.html.eex layout
|> render(...)
```

or shorter:

```
conn
|> put_root_layout(false)
|> render(..., layout: false)
```